# Why my SOAP based project works without inclusion of the Apache CXF's dependencies?

Tags: java, soap, cxf, jax-ws

So this is my first time ever trying SOAP with Apache CXF. I copy the entire project(Spring based) sample into my workspace, run it and it just works. I'm so confused because I don't think I've included any dependencies related to Apache CXF, I've searched any folder, nothing. To my understanding that Tomcat by itself doesn’t support JAX-WS, so I need a JAX-WS runtime. But even if it does, Apache CXF is the reference implementation means, it's an independent project from the JAX-WS so I need to include it.

I also found these declarations `cfx-context.xml`:

```
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>
 <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
```

I don't thing there is such `cfx-servlet.xml` or `cxf.xml` within `META-INF` folder or anywhere.

I need the explanation to understand why this works because I'll work with some SOAP codes for the next several days.

Tools and libraries used:
 Eclipse IDE
- TomEE container/server
- Spring's jars

Comment: Show your code. How can anyone know what you do?

Comment: @mentallurg. And what code does exactly in my case?

Comment: It is not clear if you have Apache CXF at all in in your code. If you show the code, then it will be clear. Depending on that there will other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are using Java 8? JAX-WS 2.2 is part of Java SE 8 (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/xml/jax-ws/index.html). Please note that was changed for future versions, in this case you need to add additional libraries.